# ATI Radeon HD 6370M, driver Ubuntu 14.04 x64

Tags: 14.04, ati, radeon, gpu-driver

Can you please tell me the proper way to install my video card in Ubuntu 14.04, if it is possible?
I am using switchable graphics.
In 13.10 I managed to install it, but I lost the the demo.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your card is supported out-of-the-box in 14.0 with the open source driver, is it not working?

Comment: My main board in my settings is Intel not Ati. When i tried to install the driver from AMD, it sad No supported card detected. I tried xorg driver also. Same message not supported. Are you saing that is preinstaled?. 10x again for the help.

Comment: Yes, fully supported with preinstalled radeon driver, see [Fully supported cards](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Fully_Supported)

Comment: I will reinstall it again and check if the driver is working properly

Comment: I tried but my main Graphics card is still Intel® Sandybridge Mobile how can I see if the driver is installed or working?

Comment: You can find out which driver is being used by doing `glxinfo | grep 'OpenGL renderer'` - see [Arch Wiki: PRIME](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME) for instructions to offload processing for specific apps using DRI_PRIME. You probably only want to offload processing for games and other 3D intensive apps, for standard desktop usage the Intel GPU should be fine.

Comment: 10x a lot, I owe you a beer, If you ever visit Romania LET ME KNOW :D

Comment: Thanks for the offer, someday I will cycle [EuroVelo 6](http://www.eurovelo6.org) all the way to Romania :)